# project publishing to windows web server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis-7

I am working with a Visual Studio 2008 (C#) project on Windows XP Pro. I am trying to publish that application using "Publish Web" wizard to a remote server which is Windows Web Server 2008 OS.

But the publishing fails every time with following error:

```
 Connecting to http://XX.XXX.XXX.XX/...
 Unable to create the Web site
 'http://XX.XXX.XXX.XX/'. The Web
 server does not appear to have
 FrontPage Server Extensions installed.
 ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped
 ========== 
 ========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I used these links:

- http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/134/install-frontpage-server-extensions/
- http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1630
- http://www.rtr.com/fpse/

I have installed FrontPage Server extensions from above links without any problems on the remote server.

And extend the Virtual Server (the "Default Web Site").

However, the problem remains. I cannot find any solution to this issue.

Comment: Great, but what if you **don't** want that user to be Administrator for your server?
I'm having the same issue.
Only Administrators can login using FPSE and VS2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok problem is solved.

it was an user authorization issue. I set the user as admin for remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with the http publishing more often than not. I've worked around it by setting up an ftp directory that maps to the web app directory and using the ftp address from the wizard.